# Datagrid ValidationRule needs reference to Row ViewModel

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, validation, datagrid

In VS-2010, for a `Datagrid` whose columns employ `ValidationRules`, is there any way to give a `ValidationRule` a reference to the row's binded viewmodel?  In certain situations, the validation logic will depend upon the current state of the viewmodel.

I have read about adding paramaters to `ValidationRules` using `DependencyObjects`.  But the examples only show binding the validation parameters to `StaticResources` (such as max & min values).  Since the `ValidationRule` is not part of the logical tree, I cannot figure how to create a parameter for the validation rule to reference the binded viewmodel of whichever `DataGridRow` is being edited.

The one workaround I know of is when `ValidationStep` is set to `UpdatedValue` - then the `Value` parameter of the `Validate` method becomes the `BindingExpression`, from which the viewmodel can be extracted.  But I need to validate before updating the viewmodel, so this doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed a workaround but it is far from elegant.  I did end up adding a `DependencyProperty` to the `ValidationRule` - but `ValidationRule` does not inherit from `DependencyObject` so you have to dump the parameters in a separate class that is a `DependencyObject`, then add an instance of that class to the `ValidationRule`.

In this case the "parameter" I'm creating for the `ValidationRule` is the `DataGrid` itself.  I had to use a binding proxy in the window resources just to accomplish this, since `ValidationRule` is not part of the logical tree.

When the `ValidationRule` actually runs `Validate`, I use the `DataGrid` instance to find the editing row, get the binded viewmodel of that row, and now I can inspect the viewmodel to determine if the proposed value is acceptable.

I could probably add some code but in all honesty there has to be a better way than this.  Already I can think of some possible bugs.  Below is the example I found the most helpful.

[Attached or dependecy Property for ValidationRule WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296507/attached-or-dependecy-property-for-validationrule-wpf)